# Unable to understand how to bind the type to response

Tags: typescript

I'm writing on a typescript code that gets the data from sdk. and below is my sample code.

```
import { ChangeEvent, useState, KeyboardEvent } from "react";
interface SearchBoxProps {
  onSearch: (searchTerm: string) => void;
}
export interface Root {
  results: Result[];
  inputIntents: any[];
  uuid: string;
}

export interface Result {
  matchedSubstrings: any[];
  value: string;
  verticalKeys: string[];
  inputIntents: any[];
}

const CustomSearchBaR = ({ onSearch }: SearchBoxProps) => {
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");
  const myApiMethod = useMyApiMethod();
  const [results, setResults] = useState<Root>();
  const handleChange = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    myApiMethod(event.target.value);
    myApiMethod.setQuery(event.target.value);
    myApiMethod
      .executeMyMethod()
      .then((res) => setResults(res));
  };

  const handleKeyDown = (event: KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
      onSearch(searchTerm);
    }
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Search..."
        value={searchTerm}
        onChange={handleChange}
        onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default CustomSearchBaR;
```

the above code returns me

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "matchedSubstrings": [],
      "value": "Extendable Dish Drying Rack",
      "verticalKeys": [
        "patents"
      ],
      "inputIntents": []
    },
    {
      "matchedSubstrings": [],
      "value": "Eyebrow Stamp",
      "verticalKeys": [
        "patents"
      ],
      "inputIntents": []
    },
    {
      "matchedSubstrings": [],
      "value": "ENERGY STORAGE AND POWER SUPPLY DEVICE",
      "verticalKeys": [
        "patents"
      ],
      "inputIntents": []
    },
    {
      "matchedSubstrings": [],
      "value": "EARPHONE",
      "verticalKeys": [
        "patents"
      ],
      "inputIntents": []
    }
  ],
  "inputIntents": [],
  "uuid": "0187998f-dd75-265b-9c55-3202bc9d1e35"
}
```

and when I do `(res) => setResults(res)`, I get the error as

> Argument of type 'MyMethodEndpointResponse | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<Root | undefined>'.

Please lemme know where I'm going wrong.

Thanks

Comment: You haven't shown us the return *type* for the API call (only the *value* which may be subtly different), so we can't say. It's also not clear why you're defining a custom interface instead of just aliasing (or even using directly) the type from the API package.

Comment: Even if you don't have direct access to that type you could do something like `useState<ReturnType<typeof myApiMethod['executeMethod']> extends Promise<infer U> ? U | never>` although that's maybe a bit of a hack

Comment: Ah. this made sense, and I'm able to solve it @JaredSmith, can you please post the 2nd comment as answer?  I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create your own `Root` interface. Typescript has a utility type that lets you get the return type of a function, unsurprisingly named `ReturnType`. It's a little trickier because that function returns a Promise, and we want the type *inside* the Promise, but we can solve that by writing another utility type:

```
type GetPromiseType<T> = T extends Promise<infer U> ? U : never;
```

then we can pair this with the `ReturnType` to extract the type of the value in the Promise returned from that method:

```
const myApiMethod = useMyApiMethod();
const [results, setResults] = useState<GetPromiseType<ReturnType<(typeof myApiMethod)['executeMyMethod']>>>();
```

Please note, if the type of the data is directly available you should use that instead since the above code isn't the most readable in the world, but you have it if you need it :)